# Find the function $y(x)$ which satisfies $1+y+xy^2+x^2y^3+x^3y^4+...+x^ny^{n+1}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to find the function $y(x)$ which satisfies $$1+y+xy^2+x^2y^3+x^3y^4+...+x^ny^{n+1}=0$$

Comment: Hint: $0 = 1+y(1+xy + (xy)^2 + \ldots + (xy)^n)$

Comment: I changed to tag to better match this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting at the $y$ term it is a geometric series with common ratio as $xy$. So use the sum for geometric series to get to the expression.